# How do I bind two objects from two different lists into one ListView controller in Xaml?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

So I have two lists one is the name of the author and the other is the quote.
I need both to go inside the same ListView controller. The name and the quote are from two different lists and it has to be that way.

```
<ListView x:Name ="CategoryListView" ItemsSource ="{Binding Authors, Binding Quotes}" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate >
        <ViewCell >
          <ViewCell.View >
            <StackLayout>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                <Label Text ="{Binding AuthorName}" FontSize="10" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding QuoteContent}" FontSize="10" TextColor="White"/>
              </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

This is how I have tried doing it and it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
public QuotePageViewModel(string category, IEnumerable<Quote> qoutes, List<Author> matchingAuthors) 
{ 
Category = category; 
Quotes = new List<Quote>(); 
Quotes = qoutes.ToList(); 
Authors = new List<Author>();
Authors = matchingAuthors.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Also what is happening, do the labels just stay empty?

Comment: @StarterPack Yes they stay empty. If I use only one binding it works and name will be displayed and with Quotes quote will be displayed.

Code:

`public QuotePageViewModel(string category, IEnumerable<Quote> qoutes, List<Author> matchingAuthors)
        {
            Category = category;
            Quotes = new List<Quote>();
            Quotes = qoutes.ToList();
            Authors = new List<Author>();
            Authors = matchingAuthors.ToList();
        }`

Comment: @StarterPack Ignore the last line with the "Concat" thingy (I edited the code) I was trying something and it didn't work. What I was trying to do was to concatenate the two lists into one so that I only needed to bind one list. But as I said it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion: 
You bind your List to a Dictionary.
We will bind your labels to Key and Value of the dictionary, in your Xaml just do this:

```
<ListView x:Name ="CategoryListView" HasUnevenRows="True">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate >
    <ViewCell >
      <ViewCell.View >
        <StackLayout>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
            <Label Text ="{Binding Key}" FontSize="10" TextColor="White"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Value}" FontSize="10" TextColor="White"/>
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell.View>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Now fill a dictionary with Authors and Quotes(this is assuming quotes and churchfathers is of same length and the indexes match, so Quote[0] matches Authors[0]). And add it as the ItemsSources of your list:

```
 var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 for(int i = 0; i<quotes.Count; i++)
 {
     dict.Add(Authors[i], quotes.ElemetAt(i));
 } 
 CategoryListView.ItemsSource = dict;
```

This should work fine for you, but keep in mind that Dictionary does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged so changes in your content during runtime will not be displayed

Comment: There is a many Quotes to one Author relation. But that shouldn't matter since the lists are of the same length. For each match an Author is added.

Comment: I have some trouble accessing stuff but I will manage eventually. I know this will work though I didn't know how I should do it. Thanks mate :)

I will mark it as the answer once I make it work.